Apache Camel Custom Component Unknown Parameters error message
I am trying to implement Hierynomus SMBJ into a Custom Component in Apache Camel. I've created the Producer, the endpoint, the configuration and the consumer. However for some reason, when added to the CamelContext, I get an error message stating that there are 3 unknown parameters as described below:
Failed to create route SMB_TO_SFTP-4: Route(SMB_TO_SFTP-4)[From[smb:some-ip:4450/shared-fo... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: smb://some-ip:4450/shared-folder?delete=true&password=xxxxxx&username=xxxxxx due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: smb://some-ip:4450/shared-folder?delete=true&password=xxxxxx&username=xxxxxx due to: There are 3 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{delete=true, password=just hid this, username=nick}].
My code is as follows after various things I've tried. Please note that I am coding in Spring Boot project with Apache camel 4:
SmbComponent class
package com.definefunction.transfer.protocol.smb;

import com.definefunction.transfer.exception.TransferRecordNotValidException;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.spi.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

@Component("smb")
public class SmbComponent extends DefaultComponent {

    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        SmbEndpoint smbEndpoint = new SmbEndpoint(uri, this);

        // Check if move and delete haven't been set at the same time.
        if (parameters.containsKey("delete") && parameters.containsKey("move")) {
            throw new TransferRecordNotValidException("An endpoint cannot delete and move a file at the same time.");
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("username")) {
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setUsername((String) parameters.get("username"));
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("password")) {
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setPassword((String) parameters.get("password"));
        }
        // Set delete option if provided
        if (parameters.containsKey("delete")) {
            String delete = (String) parameters.get("delete");
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setDelete(Boolean.parseBoolean(delete));
        }

        // Set move option if provided
        if (parameters.containsKey("move")) {
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setMove((String) parameters.get("move"));
        }

        // Set delay option if provided
        if (parameters.containsKey("delay")) {
            String delay = (String) parameters.get("delay");
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setDelay(Long.parseLong(delay));
        }

        // Set readLock option if provided
        if (parameters.containsKey("readLock")) {
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setReadLock((String) parameters.get("readLock"));
        }

        // Set readLockMinAge option if provided
        if (parameters.containsKey("readLockMinAge")) {
            String readLockMinAge = (String) parameters.get("readLockMinAge");
            smbEndpoint.getConfiguration().setReadLockMinAge(Long.parseLong(readLockMinAge));
        }

        //setProperties(smbEndpoint, parameters);
        return smbEndpoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }
}

SmbConfiguration class
package com.definefunction.transfer.protocol.smb;

import com.definefunction.transfer.exception.TransferRecordNotValidException;
import org.apache.camel.spi.UriParam;
import org.apache.camel.spi.UriParams;

import java.util.Map;

import static com.definefunction.transfer.utilities.Utilities.sanitizeParametersInURL;

@UriParams
public class SmbConfiguration {

    private String server;

    private int port;

    private String shareName;
    private String path;

    @UriParam
    private String username;
    @UriParam
    private String password;
    @UriParam
    private String directory;
    private String fileName;
    @UriParam
    private boolean delete;
    @UriParam
    private String move;
    @UriParam
    private long delay;
    @UriParam
    private String readLock;

    private String domain;
    @UriParam
    private long readLockMinAge;

    public SmbConfiguration(String uri) {
        String baseUrl = uri.split("\\?")[0];
        String[] parts = baseUrl.split("/");

        // The server or hostname should always be there with or without a port.
        String[] serverParts = parts[2].split(":");
        if (serverParts.length > 0) {
            this.server = serverParts[0];
            if (serverParts.length > 1) {
                this.port = Integer.parseInt(serverParts[1]);
            }
        } else {
            throw new TransferRecordNotValidException("Hostname of the endpoint could not be found in url: " + sanitizeParametersInURL(uri));
        }

        if (parts.length >= 3) {
            // Should be a sharename
            this.shareName = parts[3];
        }

        if (parts.length >= 4) {
            // Extract Directory
            StringBuilder directoryPath = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 4; i < parts.length; i++) {
                directoryPath.append("/").append(parts[i]);
            }
            this.directory = directoryPath.toString();
        }
    }

    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public String getShareName() {
        return shareName;
    }

    public void setShareName(String shareName) {
        this.shareName = shareName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDirectory() {
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(String directory) {
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public boolean isDelete() {
        return delete;
    }

    public void setDelete(boolean delete) {
        this.delete = delete;
    }

    public String getMove() {
        return move;
    }

    public void setMove(String move) {
        this.move = move;
    }

    public long getDelay() {
        return delay;
    }

    public void setDelay(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public String getReadLock() {
        return readLock;
    }

    public void setReadLock(String readLock) {
        this.readLock = readLock;
    }

    public long getReadLockMinAge() {
        return readLockMinAge;
    }

    public void setReadLockMinAge(long readLockMinAge) {
        this.readLockMinAge = readLockMinAge;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }
}

SmbEndpoint
package com.definefunction.transfer.protocol.smb;

import org.apache.camel.Component;
import org.apache.camel.Consumer;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.Producer;
import org.apache.camel.spi.UriEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.spi.UriParam;
import org.apache.camel.spi.UriParams;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint;

import java.io.IOException;

@UriEndpoint(firstVersion = "1.0.0", scheme = "smb", title = "smb", syntax = "smb")
public class SmbEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint {

    @UriParam
    private final SmbConfiguration configuration;

    public SmbEndpoint(String uri, SmbComponent component) {
        super(uri, component);
        this.configuration = new SmbConfiguration(uri);

    }


    @Override
    public String getEndpointBaseUri() {
        return super.getEndpointBaseUri();
    }

    @Override
    public Producer createProducer() throws Exception {
        return new SmbProducer(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingletonProducer() {
        return super.isSingletonProducer();
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer createConsumer(Processor processor) throws Exception {
        return new SmbConsumer(this, processor);
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
        return super.getComponent(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }

    public SmbConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }
}

At first I found out that I might needed to annotate some things like the endpoint and the Component. So I did that. I also found out that at startup, within the doBuild() method of the DefaultComponent class the Configurers remain empty. However the Default name is filled in
    protected void doBuild() throws Exception {
        if (this.defaultName == null) {
            org.apache.camel.spi.annotations.Component ann = (org.apache.camel.spi.annotations.Component)ObjectHelper.getAnnotation(this, org.apache.camel.spi.annotations.Component.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                String name = ann.value();
                if (name.contains(",")) {
                    name = StringHelper.before(name, ",");
                }

                this.defaultName = name;
            }
        }

        if (this.defaultName != null) {
            if (this.componentPropertyConfigurer == null) {
                this.componentPropertyConfigurer = PluginHelper.getConfigurerResolver(this.getCamelContext()).resolvePropertyConfigurer(this.defaultName + "-component-configurer", this.getCamelContext()); // Returns null
            }

            if (this.endpointPropertyConfigurer == null) {
                this.endpointPropertyConfigurer = PluginHelper.getConfigurerResolver(this.getCamelContext()).resolvePropertyConfigurer(this.defaultName + "-endpoint-configurer", this.getCamelContext()); // Returns null
            }
        }

    }

Also, when I added the component to the Camel Context, I first did this while starting the application. I am now doing it after the application is started:
@Bean
    CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
                try {
                    if (transferLogging.get(0).getTransferId() == null) {
                        transferLogging.remove(0);
                    }
                    context.setLogMask(true);
                    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolEnabled(true);
                    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolDirectory("/tmp/cachedir");
                    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolThreshold(64 * 1024);
                    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setBufferSize(256 * 1024);
                    context.setStreamCaching(true);

                    // Initial routes from the database
                    camelService = new CamelService(urlBuilderService,camelContext,recordService, progressEventService, inProgressService, dynamicResolver, transferLogging);
                    camelService.AddSystemRoutes();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
                // Empty implementation
                camelContext.addComponent("smb", new SmbComponent());
            }
        };
    }

I really wanted to fix this myself, I've been messing with ChatGpt for a day now and Stackoverflow is kinda my last resort. I've been searching the interne, however I couldn't exactly find something that matched my issue. Not saying it isn't there, just that I don't understand why this is happening, I might also not recognize identical situations. If you need any more information, please ask me.
